# Equality (==) for double (vs. long double) in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, equality

In my assignment I had been asked to say why the following code prints mis-match
the code checks for `a == square (sqrt(a))`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#define sqr(x) ((x) * (x))
int main() {
        double a = 4.0*atan(1.0); // pi
        double b = sqrt(a); // square-root of pi
        if (a == sqr(b)) // pi is equal to
        // square of square-root of pi?
                cout << "Match" << endl;
        else
                cout << "Mis-Match" << endl;
        return 0;

}
```

I know that this type of problem are do to the fact that floating point numbers are approximate representation and for checking equality one should check for almost equality case i.e. `|a-b|<epsilon`,
where epsilon is taken to be 1e-8 or any other suitable value.

**But when I replace `double` with `long double` the code executed to print `Match`.**

So I want to know when == works and when it does not.

Comment: _"I want to know when == works and when it does not."_  It would require **a lot** of reading to be able to think like a floating point processor.  Very good programmers will assume that they aren't certain.

Comment: Because: more precision for `long double`?

Comment: same code, same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810428/whats-wrong-with-my-code-its-showing-mismatch-even-when-it-should-show-match/65810501?noredirect=1#comment116360159_65810501

Comment: `==` always "works", it just happens rarely that two floating point numbers that are a result of some calcualtion happen to be equal

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 hm... sometimes a teacher will tell an _entire class_ to bring the same question here.

Comment: " case i.e. |a-b|<epsilon, where epsilon is taken to be 1e-8 or any other suitable value." is a myth. Picking the approximation technique (additive or multiplicative or another scheme) depends on the context, as does the tolerance.

Comment: `4.0*atan(1.0)` is not guaranteed to equal *pi* either. `atan` is not required by any common standard to return the best floating point value possible. (Interestingly `std::sqrt` must return the best floating point value possible under IEEE754.(

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare floating point values.  Must read: [*What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103162.103163).  Most floating point values are only approximation.

Comment: we are so much used to real numbers as they are used in maths that sometimes one forgets that any number that one can write down in reality has limited precision. In some sense real numbers is just a nice trick so we can do maths with numbers, but in reality I have not seen a real number yet

Comment: `==` always works; `a == b` evaluates to true if and only if `a` equals `b`. The question you want to ask is when are two values computed with floating-point equal. The answer is that depends on how they were computed, and there is, in general, no simple way of telling because error analysis of numerical computations is very complicated.

Comment: Detail: "floating point numbers are approximate representation" --> All finite floating point values are _exact_ - each FP values has an exact decimal and exact binary representation.  Often an operation forms a value that is approximate to math result, but the FP result is exact.